# MQTT AND Web Server connections within same sketch on NodeMCU

Tags: c++, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am unable to establish a http server connection and MQTT connection at the same time on an ESP8266 (Nodemcu) using libraries ESPAsyncWebServer and PubSubClient. My intention is to push over the air updates using the library AsyncElegantOTA while at the same time using MQTT for something else. Everything works great until I attempt to establish the HTTP server connection using the method below: `setup_http()`. I have tried establishing the connection within setup but that fails immediately and the connection cycles repeatedly. So, I have attempted to establish the connection within the loop function but that is failing as well. Is it possible to run both in the same sketch?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Secrets.h"
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <AsyncElegantOTA.h>
#define IOT_PUBLISH_TOPIC "pubout"
#define IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC "subin"

bool isServerStarted = false;

time_t now;
time_t nowish = 1510592825;

BearSSL::X509List cert(cacert);
BearSSL::X509List client_crt(client_cert);
BearSSL::PrivateKey key(privkey);

WiFiClientSecure net;
PubSubClient client(net);

void NTPConnect(void)
{
  Serial.print("Setting time using SNTP");
  configTime(TIME_ZONE * 3600, 0 * 3600, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  now = time(nullptr);
  while (now < nowish)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  Serial.println("done!");
  struct tm timeinfo;
  gmtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
  Serial.print("Current time: ");
  Serial.print(asctime(&timeinfo));
}

String get_wifi_status()
{
  switch (WiFi.status())
  {
  case WL_IDLE_STATUS:
    return String("Wifi is changing modes.");
    break;

  case WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL:
    return String("SSID: '") + WIFI_SSID + " is not available.";
    break;

  case WL_CONNECTED:
    return String("Connected to ") + WIFI_SSID;
    break;

  case WL_CONNECT_FAILED:
    return String("Could not connect to ") + WIFI_SSID;
    break;

  case WL_DISCONNECTED:
    return String("Wifi not in station mode.");
    break;

  default:
    return String("Wifi status error");
  }
}

void setup_network()
{
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println("");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
    Serial.println("...");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(get_wifi_status());
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void messageReceived(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
    //handle messages
}

void setup_mqtt()
{
  delay(3000);
  NTPConnect();

  net.setTrustAnchors(&cert);
  net.setClientRSACert(&client_crt, &key);

  client.setServer(MQTT_HOST, 8883);
  client.setCallback(messageReceived);

  Serial.println("Connecting to IOT");

  while (!client.connect(THINGNAME))
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  if (!client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("IoT Timeout!");
    return;
  }
  // Subscribe to a topic
  client.subscribe(IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);

  Serial.println("IoT Connected!");
}

void setup_http()
{
  AsyncWebServer server(80);
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
            { request->send(200, "text/plain", "Hi! I am a http server."); });

  server.begin();
  AsyncElegantOTA.begin(&server); // Start ElegantOTA
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  setup_network();
  setup_mqtt();
  // setup_http(); //Does not work here and crashes before MQTT connects. So, I moved to loop but that doesn't work either.
}

void loop()
{
  now = time(nullptr);

  if (!client.connected())
  {
    setup_mqtt();
  }

  if (isServerStarted == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Attempting to start http server");
    delay(3000);
    setup_http();
    isServerStarted = true;
    Serial.println("It crashes before we get here");
  }

  else
  {
    client.loop();

    // BEGIN Loop code    

  }
}
```

Exception:

```
User exception (panic/abort/assert)
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Unhandled C++ exception: OOM

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffd20 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0000
3ffffd20:  3fff199c 3fff169c 000000ff 00000000  
3ffffd30:  000000fe 00000000 00000000 00000000
3ffffd40:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
3ffffd50:  3fff3198 00000000 3fff31a4 00000000  
3ffffd60:  00000000 402089c6 00000c08 4021f12e  
3ffffd70:  00000000 00000020 00000c08 4021f14d  
3ffffd80:  3fff63ec 402089c6 00000c08 4021e832
3ffffd90:  3ffffda0 3ffffdec 3ffffde4 402089c6
3ffffda0:  cca8cca9 00000000 3fff4554 40208bd6
3ffffdb0:  c0afc0ae c027c023 c028c024 c013c009
3ffffdc0:  c014c00a c031c02d c032c02e 00000000
3ffffdd0:  c02ac026 c00ec004 c00fc005 009d009c
3ffffde0:  c09dc09c c0a1c0a0 003d003c 0035002f
3ffffdf0:  c012c008 c00dc003 0000000a 4021e813
3ffffe00:  00000000 3ffffe9c 3ffffe94 3fff6804
3ffffe10:  00000000 00000000 3fff4554 40209108
3ffffe20:  3fff1698 00000000 00000000 4025ebd3
3ffffe30:  007a1200 3fff4554 00000040 4025a222
3ffffe40:  007a1200 32087824 00000000 00000000
3ffffe50:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
3ffffe60:  40106105 002da5e3 3fff13d8 00000000
3ffffe70:  3fff0af0 3fff13d8 00000001 00000000
3ffffe80:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
3ffffe90:  00000000 3ffffe9c 00000000 4021f24a
3ffffea0:  3ffe8ff8 3fff4554 3fff61ec 402074f2
3ffffeb0:  3ffffee0 00000000 3fff1ac0 00000001
3ffffec0:  000022b3 3fff4554 3ffe8ff8 00000001
3ffffed0:  000022b3 3fff4554 3ffe8ff8 402093b4
3ffffee0:  40224b24 b781db12 40224b24 b781db12
3ffffef0:  00000000 00000000 3fff0ff8 40222932
3fffff00:  00004b4f 3fff4554 3fff0ff8 4020426c
3fffff10:  00000002 3fff1218 3fff610c 40220395
3fffff20:  00000000 00000000 3ffe8e9c 00000000
3fffff30:  00000000 3fff1218 3ffe967c 4021bce0
3fffff40:  4021bcd4 3fff1218 3ffe967c 3fff1370
3fffff50:  3fffdad0 3fff4554 3fff1044 40204518
3fffff60:  00000000 00000000 00000001 4021c200
3fffff70:  40224b24 3fff4554 3fff1044 40201e97
3fffff80:  402039cc feefeffe 40222b18 40222afc
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffe88e4 40201f15
3fffffa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 4021ebb7
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 40101225
<<<stack<<<

0x402089c6 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >::__allocated_ptr(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0>*) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:53
 (inlined by) std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> >&) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:97
0x4021f12e in raise_exception at core_esp8266_postmortem.cpp:?
0x4021f14d in __unhandled_exception at ??:?
0x402089c6 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >::__allocated_ptr(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0>*) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:53
 (inlined by) std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> >&) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:97
0x4021e832 in operator new(unsigned int) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/abi.cpp:47
0x402089c6 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >::__allocated_ptr(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0>*) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:53
 (inlined by) std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> >&) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:97
0x40208bd6 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0> > >::get() at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/allocated_ptr.h:85
 (inlined by) std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0>::__shared_count<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>>(br_x509_minimal_context*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context> >) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/shared_ptr_base.h:681
 (inlined by) std::__shared_ptr<br_x509_minimal_context, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)0>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context> >) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1371
 (inlined by) std::shared_ptr<br_x509_minimal_context>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context> >) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/shared_ptr.h:408
 (inlined by) std::shared_ptr<br_x509_minimal_context> std::allocate_shared<br_x509_minimal_context, std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context>>(std::allocator<br_x509_minimal_context> const&) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/shared_ptr.h:860
 (inlined by) std::shared_ptr<br_x509_minimal_context> std::make_shared<br_x509_minimal_context>() at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/shared_ptr.h:876
 (inlined by) BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::_installClientX509Validator() at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:1063
0x4021e813 in operator new(unsigned int) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/abi.cpp:41
0x40209108 in BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::_connectSSL(char const*) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:1134
0x4025ebd3 in ip_chksum_pseudo at /home/earle/src/esp-quick-toolchain/arduino/tools/sdk/lwip2/builder/lwip2-src/src/core/inet_chksum.c:395
0x4025a222 in tcp_output at /home/earle/src/esp-quick-toolchain/arduino/tools/sdk/lwip2/builder/lwip2-src/src/core/tcp_out.c:1361
0x40106105 in ets_timer_arm_new at ??:?
0x4021f24a in delay at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring.cpp:54
0x402074f2 in ClientContext::connect(ip4_addr*, unsigned short) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/include/ClientContext.h:148
 (inlined by) WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, unsigned short) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClient.cpp:162
0x402093b4 in BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::connect(char const*, unsigned short) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:232
0x40224b24 in DhcpServer::add_end(unsigned char*) at ??:?
0x40224b24 in DhcpServer::add_end(unsigned char*) at ??:?
0x40222932 in BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned short) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:245
0x4020426c in PubSubClient::connect(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned char, bool, char const*, bool) at .pio\libdeps\nodemcu\PubSubClient\src/PubSubClient.cpp:190
0x40220395 in uart_write at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/uart.cpp:544
0x4021bce0 in HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/HardwareSerial.h:194
0x4021bcd4 in HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/HardwareSerial.h:191
0x40204518 in PubSubClient::connect(char const*) at .pio\libdeps\nodemcu\PubSubClient\src/PubSubClient.cpp:167     
0x4021c200 in Print::println(char const*) at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/Print.cpp:194
0x40224b24 in DhcpServer::add_end(unsigned char*) at ??:?
0x40201e97 in setup_mqtt() at src/main.cpp:133
0x402039cc in messageReceived(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int) at src/main.cpp:114
0x40222b18 in std::_Function_handler<void (char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int), void (*)(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/std_function.h:271
0x40222afc in std::_Function_handler<void (char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int), void (*)(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, char*&&, unsigned char*&&, unsigned int&&) at c:\users\myusername\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\10.3.0\bits/std_function.h:289
0x40201f15 in setup at src/main.cpp:171
0x4021ebb7 in loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp:198
0x40101225 in cont_wrapper at C:\Users\myusername\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\cores\esp8266/cont.S:81


last failed alloc call: 402089C6(3080)

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

last failed alloc caller: 0x402089c6

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16
tail 4
chksum 0xcc
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4
tail 4
chksum 0xc9
csum 0xc9
v000b9e90
~ld
```

Comment: OOM is "out of memory". C++ tried to allocate an object and couldn't. This means one of two things: either the heap has become corrupted so that `malloc()` failed, or you're just out of memory. Since this happens very early on, it's most likely you're out of memory. The ESP8266 has very little RAM and crypto tends to chew it up quickly. If this is the case your options are going to be to simplify your program so that there's enough RAM left to run or move to a CPU with more resources like an ESP32.

Comment: I have switched to an ESP32 and it's working! A good bit had to be changed in the sketch to resolve compatibility issues with several libraries but both the mqtt client and http server are now running in the same sketch. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

In `setup_http()`, you declared `server` as a variable local to the function. That means when the function returns, the variable (and web server) will be destroyed, which will lead to some seriously undefined behavior, like a crash.

You need to make sure that `server` exists and is valid for the lifetime of the web server, so you should declare it outside of the function, as a global or static variable.

For instance,

```
AsyncWebServer server(80);

void setup_http()
{
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
            { request->send(200, "text/plain", "Hi! I am a http server."); });

  server.begin();

...
```

This will ensure that `server` isn't destroyed while you're still using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this and get an unhandled exception before MQTT has a chance to connect.

Comment: What’s the exception? Please edit the question to include it. Also the ESP Exception Decoder’s output would help.

Comment: I have added the exception decoder's output to the original post.